# Error while trying to print PathBuf, borrow later captured here by closure

Tags: rust

I was trying out a Rust CLI tutorial which was about creating a CLI app for searching a pattern in a text file. I tried altering the code to improve it using anyhow for better error reporting. The code looks like this:

```
use anyhow::{Context, Result};
use clap::Parser;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    pattern: String,
    file_path: std::path::PathBuf,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let args = Cli::parse();
    let file_path_ref = &args.file_path;
    println!(
        "Searching {} in file {}",
        args.pattern,
        args.file_path.display()
    );

    let file = File::open(args.file_path)
        .with_context(|| format!("unable to open file: {}", file_path_ref.display()))?;
    let file_reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for maybe_line in file_reader.lines() {
        let line = maybe_line.with_context(|| "unable to read line from the file")?;
        if line.contains(&args.pattern) {
            println!("{}", line);
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

The problem is, its not compiling for me as I think that the `File::open` becomes the owner of the `file_path` variable.

The error message is:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `args.file_path` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:21:27
   |
13 |     let args = Cli::parse();
   |         ---- binding `args` declared here
14 |     let file_path_ref = &args.file_path;
   |                         --------------- borrow of `args.file_path` occurs here
...
21 |     let file = File::open(args.file_path)
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `args.file_path` occurs here
22 |         .with_context(|| format!("unable to open file: {}", file_path_ref.display()))?;
   |                                                             ------------- borrow later captured here by closure
```

Is there a way to just let the `File::open` function just borrow and not take the ownership?

Comment: Try `let file = File::open(&args.file_path)`?

Comment: Oh, yeah, it works. Didn't gave it a try sooner, don't know why. Thanks @AbdulNiyasPM